# On Stack Overflow, do we need a separate tag for the language of programmers?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

As part of a crusade against the ambiguous [[language]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language) tag, I've been categorizing the various posts into what tags they will eventually need to belong in. We already have tags for the majority of these, from [[rtl]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtl) and [[language-detection]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-detection) on the spoken side to [[language-features]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-features) on the computing side.

One kind of question which I have not yet found an existing concrete tag for is the intersection of these - questions about the language of programmers. That is, the very terminology we use in our field. Questions like the following:

- [What does “performant” software actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112743/)
- [which spelling of adapter is standard in programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076321/)
- [[Raise|Trigger|Fire|…] an event?!?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888687/)

For my current progress, there are 8 such questions tagged with [language], but I'd be surprised if I didn't find any more. I think these are somewhat valuable questions that could use their own tag. Do you agree that they could use their own tag? And if they could, what should that tag be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[[terminology]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminology)

(There are 299 questions on SO with this tag).

Comment: And those 3 mentioned are now retagged.

Comment: I've gone through. 297/299 questions tagged [terminology] all refer to this concept. It's perfect. I'm amazed I didn't see it. The other two are a migrated question that brings up a separate question for me to ask, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719635/is-c-said-to-be-a-character-or-a-string-in-ruby-or-both , which I would probably retag to [language-features] since it is about the characteristics of Ruby more than the terminology itself.

Comment: @ccomet: To answer the question you're about to ask, flag the inappropriately-tagged migrated question to be deleted by a moderator.

Comment: @TheCat Is "deletion" really the best answer for any other-site question migrated to Meta?

Comment: @ccomet: If it's mistagged and old? Yes.  So far, whenever I've flagged for that (check the [wtf] retag Q for two I know you can find links to), I've asked "remove [XXX] tag or delete question?", and, as far as I can tell, it's just been deleted.

Comment: @TheCat Generally any question that ends up migrated to Meta will be "mistagged" because of the tag differences. That said, this particular question makes sense to just obliterate anyway. I had flagged it a while ago anyway.

Comment: @ccomet: Generally, yes, but we want to leave them up as a signpost.  It can even be useful to keep the tags on them (but I wouldn't be opposed to deleting all tags from migrated posts, for example, but that could screw with searching).  If someone discovers a problem (which seems rare), we can flag.  Remember that with migrated questions, the content already exists somewhere else, all we're deleting is the signpost that probably wouldn't have existed in "ideal" circumstances anyway.

Comment: There's also ["jargon"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jargon), which should probably be merged with "terminology" as well. I'll go ahead and untag them... should the tag be deleted by a diamond mod?

Comment: Addendum: [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined) is locked, so I can't edit out the jargon tag.